# Changing Displayed Card In Sencha Touch From The Controller

Tags: sencha-touch

Once I have signed in I want the sign in page to be replaced with the dashboard page but for some reason I can't get the card to change as I cant get a refrence to it that will accept the setActiveItem method.

app.js

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true
});

Ext.application({
    views: [
        'MainPanel'
    ],
    name: 'MyApp',
    controllers: [
        'MainController'
    ],

    launch: function() {

        Ext.create('MyApp.view.MainPanel', {fullscreen: true});
    }

});
```

MainController.js

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.MainController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    alias: 'controller.mainController',

    config: {
    },

    init: function(application) {
        this.control({
            'button[action=submitSigninemEmail]': {
                tap: 'signinemEmailFnc'
            }
        });
    },

    signinemEmailFnc: function() {

        var email_fld = Ext.getCmp('signinemEmail').getValue();
        var password_fld = Ext.getCmp('signinemPassword').getValue();

        var md5password = MD5(password_fld);

        Ext.data.JsonP.request({
            url: 'http://www.solumac.co.uk/clients/uwana/v2/ajax/sencha.php',
            params: {
                method: 'signinem',
                callback: 'signinem',
                email: email_fld,
                password: md5password
            },
            callback: function(result, params) {
                if (result === true) {
                    if (params.status === true){
                        console.log('signed in');
                        MyApp.views.MainPanel.setActiveItem('dashboard', {type:'slide', direction:'left'});
                    } else {
                        console.log(params.message);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }
});
```

MainPanel.js

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MainPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.mainPanel',

    config: {
        layout: {
            type: 'card'
        },
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'container',
                id: 'signinem',
                layout: {
                    type: 'fit'
                },
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'titlebar',
                        docked: 'top',
                        id: 'signinemTitleBar',
                       title: 'Sign In',
                        items: [
                            {
                                xtype: 'button',
                                id: 'signinemButtonBack',
                                ui: 'back',
                                text: 'Back'
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: 'button',
                                align: 'right',
                                id: 'signinemButtonSignUp',
                                text: 'Sign Up'
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'container',
                        id: 'signinemPadding',
                        padding: 10,
                        width: '100%',
                        items: [
                            {
                                xtype: 'fieldset',
                                id: 'signinemFacebookSet',
                                title: 'Sign In with Facebook',
                                items: [
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'button',
                                        id: 'signinemFacebook',
                                        margin: 10,
                                        width: '',
                                        text: 'Facebook'
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: 'fieldset',
                                id: 'signinemEmailSet',
                                title: 'Sign In with Email',
                                items: [
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'textfield',
                                        id: 'signinemEmail',
                                        margin: 10,
                                        label: 'email'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'passwordfield',
                                        id: 'signinemPassword',
                                        margin: 10,
                                        label: 'Password'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'checkboxfield',
                                        action: 'changeField',
                                        id: 'signinemShow',
                                        itemId: 'mycheckbox',
                                        margin: 10,
                                        label: 'show password',
                                        labelWidth: '80%'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'button',
                                       action: 'submitSigninemEmail',
                                        id: 'signinemSubmit',
                                        margin: 10,
                                        text: 'Submit'
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
           },
            {
                xtype: 'container',
                id: 'dashboard',
                layout: {
                    type: 'fit'
                },
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'titlebar',
                        docked: 'top',
                        id: 'dashboardBar',
                        title: 'Dashboard'
                    }
                ]
            },
        listeners: [
            {
                fn: 'onSigninemShowCheck',
                event: 'check',
                delegate: '#signinemShow'
            },
            {
                fn: 'onSigninemShowUncheck',
                event: 'uncheck',
                delegate: '#signinemShow'
            }
        ]
    },

    onSigninemShowCheck: function(checkboxfield, e, options) {
        alert('show password');
    },

    onSigninemShowUncheck: function(checkboxfield, e, options) {
        alert('hide password');
    }

});
```

I believe the problem lies with the line...

```
MyApp.views.MainPanel.setActiveItem('dashboard', {type:'slide', direction:'left'});
```

...which doesn't work, but have drawn a complete blank as to what should replace it.

Answer (score 0):

if you change

```
Ext.create('MyApp.view.MainPanel', {fullscreen: true});
```

to

```
Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('MyApp.view.MainPanel'));
```

in your app.js, then in your controller change

```
MyApp.views.MainPanel.setActiveItem('dashboard', {type:'slide', direction:'left'});
```

to

```
Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(Ext.create('dashboard'),{
// other stuff
});
```

and add dashboard to your views array in app.js I believe it should work

Answer (score 0):

You can't just do a setActiveItem of the id string like you did above:

```
MyApp.views.MainPanel.setActiveItem('dashboard', {type:'slide', direction:'left'});
```

You first have to get the reference to the component using Ext.getCmp().

Also, MyApp.views.MainPanel is a class name, and not an instance. You would need to get the specific instance object, and then use it to set the active item.

Here's some code that will work for you:

```
var mypanel = Ext.ComponentQuery('mainPanel')[0];
var active = Ext.getCmp('dashboard');
mypanel.setActiveItem(active, {type: 'slide', direction: 'left'});
```

I'm also including a 1 file application that does what you want:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.mypanel',

    config: {
        layout: {
            type: 'card'
        },
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'titlebar',
                docked: 'top',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        handler: function(button, event) {
                            var comp = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('mypanel')[0];
                            var active = Ext.getCmp('c1');
                            comp.setActiveItem(active);
                        },
                        text: 'one'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        handler: function(button, event) {
                            var comp = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('mypanel')[0];
                            var active = Ext.getCmp('c2');
                            comp.setActiveItem(active);
                        },
                        text: 'two'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                xtype: 'container',
                html: 'Hello, first container',
                id: 'c1'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'container',
                html: 'hello, second container',
                id: 'c2'
            }
        ]
    }

});
```